# How to plot % change across X candles in Tradingview Pine Script?

Tags: plot, syntax-error, pine-script

So I'm simply trying to draw green triangles below the locations where the closing price changes by 20% over 5 candles. Pine script gives an syntax error for plotshape. Can't you place a condition in plotshape?

```
study(title="20% change in 5 candles", overlay=true)

var Diff = 0
var PercentChange = 0

// Identify % change 5 candles away
Diff = close - close[5]
PercentChange = Diff / close[5]

// Plot signals to chart
   plotshape(series=PercentChange > 0.2, title="Here", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, text="here")

// Send out an alert if this candle meets our conditions
alertcondition(PercentChange > 0.2, title="20% change in 5 candles!", message="20% change in 5 candles")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. var `Diff = 0` and `var PercentChange` initialized as `int`, but later you assigning it to `float` values of close.
   Use
   `var float = 0` or  `var Diff = 0.0`.
2. Later you need to reassign `var` values with `:=` operator instead of `=`:
   `Diff := close - close[5]`.
3. Erroneous extra indent before plotshape function.

```
//@version=4
study(title="20% change in 5 candles", overlay=true)

var float Diff = 0
var PercentChange = 0.0

// Identify % change 5 candles away
Diff := close - close[5]
PercentChange := Diff / close[5]

// Plot signals to chart
plotshape(series=PercentChange > 0.2, title="Here", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, text="here")

// Send out an alert if this candle meets our conditions
alertcondition(PercentChange > 0.2, title="20% change in 5 candles!", message="20% change in 5 candles")
```